# Specify a range of numbers as an argument

Tags: python, arguments, range

I'm curious as to how to take in a range of numbers as a given argument. For example, for the option -s, a user can specify a range of numbers, ie. 32:53. That range is then stored and applied later in the code. Would the following code allow for one to do this? (With all the appropriate getopt lines above and below, of course).

```
for opt, value in opts:
    if opt in ('-h', '--help')
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
    elif opt in ('-s', '--set')
        variable['set'] = range()
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: I recommend you to not store them in a `range` (aka array), but as two variables `min` and `max` instead. This prevents you from running out of memory if a user specifies a range of a billion.

Comment: @Gregor Not if he's using python3.

Comment: @Gregor: And `min` & `max` shadow Python builtins so would be a *bad* idea.

Comment: Using version 2.7, fyi, so thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @SiHa Haha, maybe there are better variable names ;), but would putting them into the `variable`- dictionary collide with the builtins ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're not using the value at all.  To create the list of numbers, you need to use the value:

```
        start, stop = value.split(":")
        variable['set'] = range(int(start), int(stop))
```